# The comprehension of Stinespring dilation in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

(Stinespring dilation) Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra and $\phi: A \rightarrow B(H)$ be a completely positive map. Then, there exist a Hilbert space $H_{1}$, and a *-representation $\pi: A \rightarrow B(H_{1})$ and operator $V:H \rightarrow H_{1}$ such that $\phi(.)=V^{\ast}\pi(.)V$. In particular, $||\phi||=||V||^{2}=||\phi(1)||$.

**In general there could be many different Stinespring dilations, but we may always assume that a dilation $(\pi, H_{1}, V)$ is  minimal in the sense that $\pi(A)VH$ is dense in $H_{1}$(which holds for the construction used in the proof). Under this minimality condition, a Stinespring dilation is unique up to unitary equivalence.**

How to explain the quotation above? How to explain there are many different Stinespring dilation? And the uniqueness of dilation under this minimality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\pi,H_1$ be a Strinespring dilation of $\phi$ on $A$. Now let $K$ be some Hilbert space with $\dim K>\dim H_1$ and $T\in B(H,K)$ some operator. Let $H_2=H_1\oplus K$,  $V_2:H\to H_2$ be given by $V_2:\xi\mapsto V\xi\oplus T\xi$, $\pi_2:A\to B(H_2)$ by $\pi_2(a)=\pi(a)\oplus 0$. Then
$$
V_2^*\pi_2(a)V_2\xi=(V^*\oplus T^*)(\pi(a)\oplus 0)(V\xi\oplus T\xi)=V^*\pi(a)V=\phi(a).
$$
So $(H_2,\pi_2,V_2)$ is a Stinespring dilation for $\phi$, such that the Hilbert spaces $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not isomorphic. And of course $\pi_2(A)V_2H$ is not dense in $H_2$, as 
$$
\overline{\pi_2(A)V_2H}=H_1\oplus 0.
$$

Now suppose that $(H_1,\pi_1,V_1)$ and $(H_2,\pi_2,V_2)$ are both Stinespring dilations with  $\pi_j(A)V_jH$  dense in $H_j$, $j=1,2$. Then you can define $U:\pi_1(A)V_1H_1\to\pi_2(A)V_2H_2$ by 
$$
U\pi_1(a)V_1\xi=\pi_2(a)V_2\xi.
$$
First we need to check that this is well defined. Note that 
$$\tag{1}
\langle \pi_1(a)V_1\xi,\pi_1(b)V_1\eta\rangle=\langle V_1^*\pi(b^*a)V_1\xi,\eta\rangle=\langle\phi(b^*a)\xi,\eta\rangle=\langle \pi_2(a)V_2\xi,\pi_2(b)V_2\eta\rangle.
$$
Then, if $\pi_1(a)V_1\xi=\pi_1(b)V_1\eta$, we get from $(1)$ that
$$
\|\pi_2(a)V_2\xi-\pi_2(b)V_2\eta\|^2=\|\pi_1(a)V_1\xi-\pi_1(b)V_1\eta\|^2=0;
$$
so $U$ is well-defined. The equality in $(1)$ also shows that $U$ is an isometry. So it is bounded and extends to an isometry $H_1\to H_2$. Being an isometry, the fact that its range is dense implies that its range is all of $H_2$, and so $U$ is a unitary. Finally, 
$$
U\pi_1(a)V_1=\pi_2(a)V_2.
$$
Putting $a=I$ (or using an approximate identity if $A$ is not unital) we get $UV_1=V_2$. And, for any $\pi_1(b)V_1\xi\in H_1$ and $a\in A$,
$$
\pi_2(a)U\,(\pi_1(b)V_1\xi)=\pi_2(a)\pi_2(b)V_2\xi=\pi_2(ab)V_2\xi=U\pi(ab)V_1\xi=U\pi_1(a)\,(\pi_1(b)V_1\xi).
$$
This shows that $\pi_2(a)U=U\pi_1(a)$ on a dense subset of $H_1$, and so everywhere. Multiplying by $U^*$ on the left, 
$$
U^*\pi(a)U=\pi_1(a),\ \ a\in A.
$$

Comment: I suppose the the map $U$ should be from $\pi_{1}(A)V_{1}H$ to $\pi_{2}(A)V_{2}H$ with $U(\pi_{1}(a)V_{1}\xi)=\pi_{2}(a)V_{2}\xi$, $\xi \in H$, right?

Comment: Yes. Corrected.

Comment: If $dimH_1=\infty$,is it also meaningful to discuss $dimK>dimH_1$?

Comment: Of course. There is more than one infinite cardinality, you know. And the proof uses explicitly that $H$ and $K$ are not isomorphic.